# How do I do server-side caching of GETs to a RPC-like "REST" service

Tags: apache-2.2, cache

We have a service that exposes a calculation service through a REST interface (accessed by `GET`). To me this sounds like a perfect candidate for caching responses, and after reading [an article by Andy King on using Apache's mod_expire for caching](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/cache/), this seemed the way to go. I basically thought setting

```
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 hour"
```

to cache the responses. The calculation service uses indexes that are updated from time to time, so it needs to refresh from time to time, but other than that, I cannot see any pitfalls. What other ways would you recommend to do server-side caching that does not mean touching the code itself?

Answer (score 3):

An `Expires` header gives you client-side caching (useful if the same client needs the same resource multiple times) but not server-side caching.

Since you're looking to cache server-side, [`mod_cache`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html) is what you need.

Comment: As in setting CacheEnable+CacheDefaultExpire 3600 (one hour)? This would effectively trigger caching _on the server_ of a given URL for one hour, right?

Comment: @oligofren It may not necessarily be that simple depending on your content (headers and other factors can interfere), but yeah, that's the idea.